# Indicate EOF / BOF in Vim?

Tags: normal-mode

Is there a way to turn on an indicator that states that this is the beginning or the end of the file in VIM?

You can do it in SEU on the iSeries, see below:

[image: The SEU editor displaying Beginning of data, End of data]

Comment: I think EOF is definitely possible. With some kind of line number display (either in a column or the ruler or statusline), the beginning is usually obvious.

Answer (score 1):

By default, vim displays a tilde in the gutter (the leftmost edge of the window) at the end of the buffer.

If you turn on line numbers with `set number` you'll see a "1" at the first line of every buffer and no number at all beyond the end of it.

Is that suitable?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't satisfied by [Vim's built in solutions for this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38874/343), then one alternative would be to highlight the first and last lines of the file:

```
:hi StartOfBuffer guibg=red ctermfg=red
:hi EndOfBuffer guibg=red ctermbg=red
:call matchadd('StartOfBuffer', '\%1l')
:call matchadd('EndOfBuffer', '.*\%$')
```

Setting up autocommands to add the matches in every buffer you open is left as an exercise for the reader.

A similar alternative would be to add a [sign](https://vimhelp.org/sign.txt) to the first and last line of the file, but I think you'd then need to update the end-of-buffer sign whenever the number of lines in the file changes.

If you don't like *any* of the above and want something really close to your screenshot, you could go really wild and set up autocommands to add actual lines of text to your buffer when you load the file, prevent editing them while its open, and remove them again before saving. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: RE: "go really wild," maybe virtual text with newer vim?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ah yes, I forgot about that because I haven't tried it yet. I think that's probably the best answer: I'll edit in an implementation if no-one else does it before me.